# PlotRange is distorting Plot

Tags: plotting

```
p1 = 
  Plot[{y = a x Tan[x], -y = -a x Cot[x]}, {x, 0, 4 π}, 
    AxesLabel -> {Subscript[k, Subscript[1, x]], Subscript[γ, x]}, 
    Ticks -> {Range[0, 4 π, π/2], Range[0, 4 π, π/2]}]
```

looks like:

[image]

```
p1 = 
  Plot[{y = a x Tan[x], -y = -a *x* Cot[x]}, {x, 0, 4 π}, 
    AxesLabel -> {Subscript[k, Subscript[1, x]], Subscript[γ, x] }, 
    Ticks -> {Range[0, 4 π, π/2], 
    Range[0, 4 π, π/2]}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 4 Pi}]
```

This function, which uses the `PlotRange` option, looks like:

[image]

Why does `PlotRange` distort the curves? The `Tan` and `Cot` become lines with the increasing angle value.

Comment: Your second plot is in no way distorted. It is simply a magnified view of a small section of your first plot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issued raised is not really a problem, but a misunderstanding on the OP's part of the results, which are entirely correct.

Comment: I thought it was a magnification problem but the curve is intact at 0 and becomes linear near the higher pi values. If it was magnified, they would all be identical.

Comment: Have a look at the original graph. The curves are 'more linear' at higher x values as well from what I can see.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is, at least, unconventional and (if I understand the task right) gives an incorrect plot. I recommend to change. Second, play with `AspectRatio`:

```
a = 1;
Clear[k, x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[{a x Tan[x], a*x*Cot[x]}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[k, Subscript[1, x]], 
    Subscript[\[Gamma], x]}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2], Range[0, 4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2]}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 4 Pi}, AspectRatio -> b, Exclusions -> Cos[x] == 0,
   ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed}], {b, 0.4, 1}]
```

giving

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to mathematica so I can't figure out if I am using functions incorrectly or if there's another problem.